# fail test on unhandled exceptions in Poltergeist

Tags: exception, poltergeist

When I add some junk to application.js I get following error from Poltergeist:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError: One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page. If you don't care about these errors, you can ignore them by setting js_errors: false in your Poltergeist configuration (see documentation for details).
```

However when I just throw and exception, it's ignored (and test fails because of page functionality missing). Can I make Poltergeist fail if page has unhandled exceptions? Or at least issue warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a bug to me - please report it on Github with steps to reproduce.

Comment: Indeed, in a dummy application all JS errors I could generates result in test failures.

Comment: Mystery solved: I had Honeybadger included in application.js. Even though it wasn't enabled/configured in test environment it would interfere with exception catching behaviour of Poltergeist.